# In AEM6, How do I hide a specific component field based on pages for certain country only?

Tags: content-management-system, aem

In AEM6, How do I hide a specific component field based on pages for certain country only ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom dialog/widget plugin to do that. This is how you attach plugin to your widget:

```xml
<title jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
       fieldLabel="Field to hide"
       plugins="hideFieldPlugin"
       name="./fieldToHide"
       xtype="textfield" />
```

Next, we need to write plugin and register it:

```js
(function ($) {
    var plugin = CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.Ext.emptyFn, {

        init: function (fieldToHide) {
            var url = CQ.HTTP.getPath();
            if (this.shouldBeHidden(url)) {
                fieldToHide.hide().disable();
            }
        },

        shouldBeHidden: function (url) {
            // some logic
            return true;
        }

    });

    CQ.Ext.ComponentMgr.registerPlugin("hideFieldPlugin", plugin);
}($CQ));
```

JavaScript file needs to be included in Classic UI edit mode. Best way to do that is to use your own custom [clientlib](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/clientlibs.html) or use already existing category, `cq.wcm.edit`.

If you have more complex logic which goes across multiple widgets, you can attach plugin on dialog level and navigate to the widget objects using `dialog.find` method.